# Is it possible to write a script that automatically changes product categories for a specific product in WooCommerce based on day of the week?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a script that can remove and add categories for specific products based on the day of the week. Currently, I'm using categories corresponding to all weekdays, so my customers can filter products and see available products for certain days of the week.

I'm not too experienced with PHP and Wordpress scripts, however, I believe there must be a way to write a script which checks for the current day of the week and if it is Monday for example, it removes category Monday and Tuesday and adds category Wednesday, Thursday etc., if they are not already added on a specific product.

I'm asking here for help to where to start since I'm lost on where at all to begin in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with WP_QUERY and search how to update product category from php function:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Thanks Bembenek! I see that my question is too broad and not specific enough. I will look into writing a script and will get back with any questions that might occur later on. I will mark this as the correct answer for now. Thanks!